# Fetch() api in react native failed - "Unhandled promise rejection"

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch

Im trying to use the Fetch api in react native but im having some issues. Whenever I try to make a POST, i get a "Unhandled promise rejection" error saying the body not allowed for GET or HEAD reequests.

The GET method works perfectly fine, it's just with POST.

Any ideas?

```
submit_task() {
    this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
    const task = {
        text: this.state.content,
        date: this.state.date
    }
    console.log(task);

    const API_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/tasks';
    fetch(API_URL, {
        methood: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(task),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application-json',
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Type: You have `methood` but you need `method`

Comment: Fetch is so garbage.
I recommend you to use axios or apisauce.
I hate fetch, because fetch + react native cause various problems.

Comment: Why do you need to set a body for a `GET` or `HEAD` request?

Comment: use axios instead of fetch because there is no timeout option and you also need middleware into fetch

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your fetch options `methood` should be `method`. Separately to that issue it's recommended to `catch` errors from Promises, something like:

```js
submit_task() {
    this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);

    const task = {
        text: this.state.content,
        date: this.state.date
    }

    const API_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/tasks';
    fetch(API_URL, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(task),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application-json',
        }
    }).catch(error => {
      // Maybe present some error/failure UI to the user here
    });
}
```

Comment: You may also want to check the response with a `.then`

Answer (score 0):

This error because of you didn't handle your exception in your API call use .catch like this

```
submit_task() {
    this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
    const task = {
        text: this.state.content,
        date: this.state.date
    }
    console.log(task);

    const API_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/tasks';
    fetch(API_URL, {
        methood: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(task),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application-json',
        }
    })
.catch(error => {
      console.log('found error', error)
    });
    }
```

Or make your api call inside try and use catch function for handling the exception or error.

```
  try {
    submit_task() {
    this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
    const task = {
        text: this.state.content,
        date: this.state.date
    }
    console.log(task);

    const API_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/tasks';
    fetch(API_URL, {
        methood: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(task),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application-json',
        }
    })
}
}
  catch(e){
   console.log('found error', error)
}
```

Comment: `try`/`catch` doesn't work if you don't `await` the promise. Only your fist snippet works.